# React Native _this2.refs.myinput.focus is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Using React-Native, I have a custom component which extends from TextInput like so:

**TextBox.js**

```
...
render() {
  return (
  <TextInput
    {...this.props}
    style={styles.textBox}/>
  );
}
...
```

**MyScene.js** (imports TextBox.js)

```
...
render() {
  render(
    <View>
      <TextBox
        rel='MyFirstInput'
        returnKeyType={'next'}
        onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.refs.MySecondInput.focus(); }}/>

      <TextBox
        ref='MySecondInput'/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I build the app and press next on the keyboard when focusing on `MyFirstInput`, I expect `MySecondInput` to be in focus, instead I get the error:

```
_this2.refs.MySecondInput.focus is not a function
```

What could the error be? Is it something to do with the scope of `this`? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because focus is a method of TextInput, and it is not present in your extended version.

You can add a focus method to TextBox.js as below:

```
focus() {
    this.refs.textInput.focus();
},
```

and add a ref to the TextInput

```
render() {
  return (
  <TextInput
    {...this.props}
    ref={'textInput'}
    style={styles.textBox}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this in the modern React Version use

```
ref = { ref => this._randomName = ref }
```

If you want to access the method use

```
this._randomName.anyMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the ref doesn't return an HTML element? I don't think it has to do anything with the this scope, it just says .focus is not a function, so it can't be executed probably because .focus does not exist on a non HTML element?

[MDN .focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) shows that it has to be an HTML element, maybe you should log the ref MySecondInput and see if you get an element?

Comment: I'm using React-Native but most of the same principles apply. I logged `this.refs.SecondInput` into the console and my component was returned so the component is returned, it's just the `.focus()` function which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: They actually implemented a .focus() when explaining about refs on the react docs. take a look at this [es6 example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to pass the reference by props from  TextBox.js for TextInput.

MyScene.js (imports TextBox.js)

```
<TextBox      
 refName={ref => { this.MySecondInput = ref; }}
/>
```

TextBox.js

```
 <TextInput
    {...this.props}
    ref={this.props.refName}
    ... />
```