# focus react input using ref throwing error when using style-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to focus on my input when I click on a button , if I use a normal input  then it will focus to this input when I click on the button `<button onClick={this.breite.setFocus}>FOCUS breite</button>` however when I try add `ref={this.breite.ref}` to my styled-component input then i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: ref.current.focus is not a function`

How can I add `this.breite.ref` to my styled input and focus it on button click?

```
import React from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Box = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  ${({ invalid }) => invalid && `
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  `}
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
`

const VCell = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
`

const Cell = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
`
const Label = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: flex-end;

`

const HoverTooltip = styled.span`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: -30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;  /* At the top of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  }
`

const Input = styled.input`
  margin: 3px 10px 0 10px !important;
  height: auto !important;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid ${palette.darkGrey};
`

const HoverTooltipWrap = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  &:hover ${HoverTooltip} {
    display: block;
  }
`

const Tooltip = styled.div`
  max-width: 80%;
`

const Units = styled.span`
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-end;
`

const Bohrfrei = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 210px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  ${media.large`
    top: 4px;
    right: -30px;
  `}
`

const BohrfreiTooltip = styled.span`
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -176px;
  right: calc(50% - 30px);
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid ${palette.orange};
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
      left: 84%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: ${palette.orange} transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  ${media.large`
    bottom: -150px;
    right: -450px;
    top: auto;
    &:after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 100%;
      left: -12px;
      margin-top: -5px;
      border-width: 6px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent ${palette.orange} transparent transparent;
    }
  `}
  ${Bohrfrei}:hover & {
    display: block;
  }
`

const Img = styled.img`
  width: 213px;
  height: 152px;
  ${media.large`
    width: 426px;
    height: 304px;
  `}
`
const utilizeFocus = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef()
  const setFocus = () => {ref.current &&  ref.current.focus()}

  return {setFocus, ref}
}
class DimensionBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.inputFocus = utilizeFocus()
    this.breite = utilizeFocus()

 }
 handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
  }

render() {
  return (
    <Box
    invalid={!this.props.isValid}
    type="number"
  >
  <VCell>

         {/* <input ref={this.breite.ref}/> */}
  <Cell>{this.props.priceFetching && console.log('fetching')}
    <Label>{this.props.label}</Label>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>

    <HoverTooltipWrap>

      <Input
        type="text"
        innerRef={this.breite.ref}
        ref={this.breite.ref}
        id={(this.props.label === 'Breite' && 'Breite' || this.props.label === 'Höhe' && 'Höhe' || undefined)}
        name={(this.props.label === 'Breite' && 'Breite' || this.props.label === 'Höhe' && 'Höhe' || undefined)}
        value={this.props.value || '' }
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        disabled={this.props.priceFetching}
      />

      {(this.props.label === 'Breite' || this.props.label === 'Breite 1' || this.props.label === 'Breite 2' || this.props.label === 'Breite 3' ||
      this.props.label === 'Höhe' || this.props.label === 'Höhe 1' || this.props.label === 'Höhe 2') &&
        <HoverTooltip>
          {(this.props.label === 'Breite' || this.props.label === 'Breite 1' || this.props.label === 'Breite 2' || this.props.label === 'Breite 3') &&
          <span>
            {`Minimale Breite: ${this.props.minWidth}mm / Maximale Breite: ${this.props.maxWidth}mm`}
            <br />
            {`Bitte beachten Sie, dass bei maximaler Breite die maximale Höhe nicht höher sein darf ${this.props.maxHeightBei}mm `}
          </span>
          }
          {(this.props.label === 'Höhe' || this.props.label === 'Höhe 1' || this.props.label === 'Höhe 2' )&&
          <span>
            {`Minimale Höhe: ${this.props.minHeight}mm / Maximale Höhe: ${this.props.maxHeight}mm`}
            <br />
            {`Bitte beachten Sie, dass bei maximaler Höhe die maximale Breite nicht breiter sein darf ${this.props.maxWidthBei}mm `}
          </span>
          }
          {/* {this.props.label === 'Höhe 2' && `Minimale Höhe: ${this.props.minHeight}mm / Maximale Höhe: ${this.props.maxHeight}mm`} */}
          {/* {this.props.label === 'Breite 3'  && `Minimale Breite: ${this.props.minWidthSmallTop}mm / Maximale Breite: ${this.props.maxWidthSmallTop}mm`} */}
        </HoverTooltip>
      }
    </HoverTooltipWrap>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Units>mm</Units> 
 <button onClick={this.breite.setFocus}>
         FOCUS breite
      </button>
  </Cell>
    {this.props.label === 'FF* Höhe' &&
      <div>
      <Bohrfrei>?
        <BohrfreiTooltip><Img src={bohrfrei}/></BohrfreiTooltip>
      </Bohrfrei>
      </div>
    }
  </VCell>
  <VCell> <Tooltip>{this.props.tooltip}</Tooltip></VCell>
  </Box>
  );
}
};

export default DimensionBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

as per this answer: [React Native _this2.refs.myinput.focus is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052630/react-native-this2-refs-myinput-focus-is-not-a-function?rq=1)

I added a focus method

```
focus() {
    this.refs.textInput.focus();
  }

<Input ref={'textInput'} />
```